# Intellij Idea Plugin, Create Kotlin PSI Visitor

Tags: kotlin, intellij-plugin

I'm creating a visitor for parsing all methods/properties inside of a `KtFile`. The problem is that, I'm hitting in debugger just one *@override* method which is `visitKtFile`, although I have put some other brake-points in another methods as well, please find attached the code for visitor.

```
public class TestVisitor extends KtVisitorVoid {

@Override
public void visitProperty(@NotNull KtProperty property) {
    super.visitProperty(property);
}

@Override
public void visitClass(@NotNull KtClass klass) {
    super.visitClass(klass);
}

@Override
public void visitNamedFunction(@NotNull KtNamedFunction function) {
    super.visitNamedFunction(function);
}

@Override
public void visitKtElement(@NotNull KtElement element) {
    super.visitKtElement(element);
}

@Override
public void visitKtFile(@NotNull KtFile file) {
    super.visitKtFile(file);
}

@Override
public void visitDeclaration(@NotNull KtDeclaration dcl) {
    super.visitDeclaration(dcl);
}
}
```

Here is the code for Action,

```
public class HelloAction extends AnAction {
public HelloAction() {
    super("Hello");
}

public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent event) {
    PsiFile psiFile = event.getData(PlatformDataKeys.PSI_FILE);
    TestVisitor visitor = new TestVisitor();
    psiFile.accept(visitor);
}
}
```

And here is the code of test class I'm trying to parse. By the structure I have I was expecting to hit the method `visitProperty` 2 times. Which is not happening at all now.

```
class TestC {
var s = true
val t = 1

fun testLog(): String {
    var test = ""
    test = "Alex"
    return test
}
}
```

Appreciate any help in creating a plugin for this amazing platform Intellij Idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`KtVisitorVoid` is a non-recursive visitor class. If you want to visit the entire tree, you need to use `KtTreeVisitorVoid` as the base class for your visitor.

Comment: Yes indeed, exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way the community can write documentation? I will be happy to add the knowledge I gather to support site.

Comment: You're welcome to submit pull requests to https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/ and https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-docs/